# Is $\{g \in G : |g| < \infty\}$ always subgroup of a group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$T(G)$ may not be a subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208312/tg-may-not-be-a-subgroup)

Let $G$ be a group, and consider $H = \{g \in G : |g| < \infty\}$.

> **Question**: Must $H$ necessarily be a subgroup of $G$?

Here, $|g|$ denotes the order of the element $g$.

Comment: What do the bars mean? Order?

Comment: This is not actually true unless you assume some more about $G$, for example it holds if $G$ is abelian.

Comment: This may be wrong, consider p. e. $\langle a,b \mid a^2 = b^2 = 1\rangle$, where $ab$ has infinite order...

Comment: I don't think this is true. What if $G$ is the group given by the presentation $\{ a, b ; a^2 = b^2 = 1 \}$.  Then $|a| =|b|=2$ but $|ab|=\infty$.

Comment: I edited the question to account for the observations after the original question was posted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general it is false that the subset of elements of a group $G$ of finite order is a subgroup. I think that the simplest, in some sense, case is that of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$. Let $s_1$ and $s_2$ be symmetries with respect to lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ through the origin. Then $s_1$ and $s_2$ have finite order (equal in fact to $2$) but the product $s_1s_2$ is a rotation whose order is finite if and only if the lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ form an angle which is a rational multiple of $2\pi$ (which is obviously not always the case).

However, the claim is true when the group $G$ is commutative. This follows immediately from the observation that if $ab=ba$ then the order of $ab$ divides the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$.